# How can I redirect the output of command prompt to DebugView on windows?

Tags: windows, debugging, redirect, console, debugview

My idea is something like

C:\myprog.exe > DebugView

but instead of creating a file named "DebugView", I would like the output of myprog.exe to be captured by DebugView.

Any comment is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As David Heffernan explained above, you need to send the output through another program, whose task is to convert all standard input to debug output using `OutputDebugString`, as linuxuser27 noted. However, I am not aware of any already existing program for such a task. You might use the following simple C# program to do that:

```
public class StdinToDebug
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) Trace.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

If you compile it to e.g. `StdinToDebug.exe`, you can use the mentioned

```
C:\myprog.exe | StdinToDebug.exe
```

Comment: +1 This makes good sense. The idea proposed by linuxuser27 probably isn't viable to apply to the original program. The point being that most of the time you presumably want the program to output to stdout.

Comment: Thanks, Mormegil! it works perfectly. Only one thing that I use Trace.WriteLine instead of Debug.WriteLine so that I can compile StdinToDebug.exe in release configuration

Comment: @Alex – If the answer helped, you might want to mark it as “accepted” (by clicking on the tick mark outline next to it). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [OutputDebugString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe it rather than redirect it:

```
C:\myprog.exe | DebugView
```

Of course, DebugView needs to read from standard input for this to work.